# How does this for loop works?

Tags: python-3.x

When I run this code, output is getting printed as 4 4 6. Please explain How does this loop work ?

```
li=[4,5,6]
for li[1] in li:
    print(li[1])
```

Comment: You're assigning li[1] as 4 in first iteration of loop, hence you get 4 printed as second term. Try printing li[1] after loop has ended, it should give you 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is assigning the values from `li` to `li[1]`

If you unroll the loop, you get:

```
li=[4,5,6]
li[1] = li[0] # li[0] = 4
print(li[1])
>>> 4 # li = [4, 4, 6]
li[1] = li[1] # li[1] = 4
print(li[1])
>>> 4 # li = [4, 4, 6]
li[1] = li[2] # li[2] = 6
print(li[1])
>>> 6 # li = [4, 6, 6]
```

you could also write it as:

```
li=[4,5,6]
for i in range(3):
  li[1] = li[i]
  print(li[1])
```

I would not recommending doing this

Comment: Hi perfect..I understood clearly..Thank you so much.. @njzk2